# ASP.NET MVC Identity Checking and Confirming Email Confirmation (Invalid Token)

Tags: asp.net, email, model-view-controller, passwords, confirmation

My application is a bit different from the standard email confirmation process and I can't seem to figure out why it isn't working correctly.

**Application logic:**

1. Check if the email has been confirmed
2. If not, set POSTed password
3. Lastly, confirm email

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{

   if (!await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(userId))
   {

      var setPassword = await UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(userId, model.NewPassword);

       if (setPassword.Succeeded)
       {
          var setConfirmedEmail = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);

          if (setConfirmedEmail.Succeeded)
          {
             ...
          }  

       }

   }

   return RedirectToAction("Login");   

 }
```

On execution setConfirmedEmail throws an "**Invalid Token**" error. I assume it is because I call IsEmailConfirmedAsync and then ConfirmEmailAsync?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Without having the time to look into it right now, I expect the call to `AddPasswordAsync` is changing the user’s security stamp, which might be causing the email-confirmation token to be invalidated.

Comment: @KirkLarkin It appears that you are right. I switched the order to confirm email > set password and it works fine. I wonder if there is a way to do it the other way around.